# How to limit content of tinymce text editor that it's droppable

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, tinymce, droppable

I'm using tinymce in inline mode and make droppable it. I want to limit content of dragged div in tinymce when drop is done. Here is my html code:

```
<div class="draggable">
    Some large text is here            
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <div id="editable4" class="editable"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JQuery code:

```
// Returns text statistics for the specified editor by id
function getStats(id) {
    var body = tinymce.get(id).getBody(), text = tinymce.trim(body.innerText || body.textContent);

    return {
        chars: text.length,
        words: text.split(/[\w\u2019\'-]+/).length
    };
}

tinymce.init({
    selector: '.editable',
    theme: 'modern',
    statusbar: false,
    inline: true,
    directionality : 'rtl',
    toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image| fontselect | fontsizeselect',
    image_advtab: true,
    plugins: [
        'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
        'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
        'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste'
    ],
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.on('keyup', function(e) {

            if (getStats(tinymce.activeEditor.id).chars > 100) {
                tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
            }

            // Check if the user has entered less than 100 words
            if (getStats(tinymce.activeEditor.id).words > 100) {
                alert("You need to enter less than 100 word.");
            }
        });//ed.onKeyUp.add
    }
});

$('.draggable').draggable({
    revert: true
});
$('.editable').droppable({
    accept: '.draggable',
    hoverClass: '.hovered',
    drop: handleDrop
});
function handleDrop(ev, ui) {
    ui.draggable.position({of: $(this), my: 'left top', at: 'left top'});
    ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
    ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
    tinyMCE.get($(this).attr('id')).setContent(ui.draggable.find('.show_list_title').html() + "<br/>" + ui.draggable.find('.detail_news_container .body-news').html());
    ui.draggable.hide();
}
```

What should i do in handleDrop function?
Thanks.